# android stroke in right to left languages

Tags: android, canvas, paint, stroke

i wrote this code to change stroke of textview, but stroke in right to left languages does not perform well.

this is my code :

```
    p.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setColor(strokeColor);
    canvas.drawText(mText, xPos, yPos, p);

    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    canvas.drawText(mText, xPos, yPos, p);
```

the output is like this

[image: output image]
[image: output image]

how can i solve this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try disabling hardware accelerated rendering in your manifest to see if that's related to the problem https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling

Comment: In Manifest, under application tag , try giving this : android:supportsRtl="true"

Comment: @samgak the problem is not related to hardware acceleration

Comment: @Vinodh already i set android:supportsRtl, but is not affect on this problem